# Change the size of subviews in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

My UITableView contains some UIScrollViews and UItextViews in its cells.

Now, I'm doing an animation, in which the frame (respectively the size) of the UITableView is changed. 
Due to `austoresizingMask` the UIScrollViews and UITextViews are also changing their size during animation, which works fine.

Unluckily the content of the UIScrollViews and UITextViews is not adjusted, which means paging in the UIScrollViews doesn't work properly after animation. 
(Calling `reloadData` on UITableView in the end of the animation fixed that. You could see, that the content of the UIScrollView was moving and then paging worked as expected. 
 
But as the UITableView was getting more rows, this didn't work anymore.)

Furthermore I would like the UITextViews to keep their formatting and simply change their fontsize.

Is there an easy way to archieve these goals?

*- Getting an animation, in which the font size of the UITextView changes fluently according to the size of the UITableViewCell. 

- Getting an animation, in which the UIScrollView content is adjusted fluently during animation*

 Thanks!